# TSQL-How to abbreviate a Table name over an entire .SQL file?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

Imagine a very long schema & table name, perhaps:   `MyTableSchemaV098AlphaCentauri.MyTableNameblahblah`.

Within a single query, it's easy to abbreviate:

```
Select A.* 
from MyTableSchemaV098AlphaCentauri.MyTableNameblahblah as A
```

How can I do this for an *entire* .sql file? Here's how I would imagine it:

```
With MyTableSchemaV098AlphaCentauri.MyTableNameblahblah as A:

  Select A.* from A

  Select top 10 A.* from A

End With
```

Comment: In your first statement create a view named `A`.  in your last statement drop the view;  Or perhaps create a temp table/pseudo temp.  Obviously there's ramifications to both these options which need to be considered; but as your problem isn't fully spelled out; we can't take those into consideration.

Comment: **_Why_** do you feel the need to do this?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: I guess the real question is why you have such long names in the first place

Comment: @gvee I know this request violates a few best practices but my carpal tunnel flares up sometimes. So typing less letters reduces actual pain. It also doesn't help that intellisense takes 5 minutes to refresh every time I create/alter a table.

Comment: @Charlieface I go by the best practice of longer, accurate names. Coding is difficult enough without remembering what QRHFMV1 means.

Comment: @PowerUser I can recommend RedGate's SQLPrompt tool for vastly improved IntelliSense & AutoComplete. It's been worth every penny for me.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend that either. But there is a golden middle, for example you don't want `tblPurchaseOrderHeaderData` nor do you want `POH1`, but `PurchaseOrder` is fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can switch to [SQLCMD mode](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2311/using-the-ssms-query-editor-in-sqlcmd-mode/?utm_source=AaronBertrand) and use `setvar`:

```
:setvar alias "sys.databases"
SELECT name FROM $(alias);
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $(alias) WHERE state = 0;
```

If you are not running the script interactively in SSMS, and can't perform this kind of token/replace with some kind of pre-parser, then no, you can't do this in T-SQL. You could do what Larnu suggests with a synonym, but this is brittle since it will kill concurrency.

```
CREATE SYNONYM dbo.alias FOR really_long_schema_name.object_name;
GO
SELECT * FROM dbo.alias;
SELECT TOP (1) * FROM dbo.alias;
GO
DROP SYNONYM dbo.alias;
```

Comment: What do you mean with "kill concurrency", exactly? Do you mean scripts like these could not execute concurrently with other scripts using the same approach, or something involving parallel query execution?

Comment: @JeroenMostert I mean that two different users couldn't use the same synonym at the same time. Not talking about parallelism at all.

Comment: OK, just confirming. There could have been something unusually interesting about synonyms that I didn't know about.